# Cannot connect/find any servers (Ubuntu gamepack)

Tags: troubleshooting

Recently downloaded Ubuntu Gamepack via USB flash drive. All went well as far as I know and except for my internet problems all is well. I do not no why, and would like some assistance in troubleshooting the problem.

The system has no problems with connecting to the modem via Firefox when the default gateway is typed into the search tab but it cannot connect to anything else. I tried the ping command but it could not find any of the websites I tried.

The last piece of information I can come up with is the output of the ifconfig command that I ran in the terminal, which I will post below this text.

**NOTE:** If any extra information is required to troubleshoot feel free to ask for it.

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:8e:47:a1  
          inet addr:192.168.0.21  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9c55:dc17:7b0a:e526/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1326711 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:180836 (180.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:42516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3342715 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:3342715 (3.3 MB)
```

Comment: Can you ping an external IP address; eg. `ping 8.8.8.8` for google's DNS?   If this works, but human addresses don't (eg. `ping google.com` fails), you have issues with DNS (domain name service; or what converts human names to the real IP addresses).

Comment: Did you really come over here to answer the same question again? Daim you are dedicated. If 8.8.8.8 is ping'ed it works. If Google.com is ping'ed it says that Google.com is an unknown host

Comment: What would you recommend doing about my dns issue?

Comment: that proves your internet & lan connection is working, but DNS isn't.  A quick fix is to add "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to the end of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.  8.8.8.8 is the ip address for google's DNS; you could use of course your ISP's or another; I use 8.8.8.8 as example (it's easy to remember).  This is a quick fix only.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by add : "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to the end of the /etc/resolv.conf file. Please elaborate

Comment: I'd use `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`; jump to end and add a line saying "nameserver 8.8.8.8" then save.  `sudo` elevates your privileges as /etc is a system folder , `vim` is my preferred editor (probably not installed for you, try `nano` or `gedit` or whatever you have/like)  The last bit was the file to edit.   (*ps: helping you on the other site was off-topic & a no-no...*)

Comment: And this is done from the terminal correct?

Comment: As you said, vim probably would not work, and it didn't but luckily nano did. I'm in the editor now but I do not think I changed anything

Comment: Thank you for your quick fix, I found my way through it all. Although I do have one last question; how do I mark this as solved?

Comment: If you `cat /etc/resolv.conf` you will see the contents of the file.  Then you do the `ping google.com` test again.  You make the change permanent via adding the nameserver to your NM (network manager) setup.   On my Lubuntu 18.10 it's Preferences->Network->DNS and add a 8.8.8.8 there. You could also add "dns-addresses 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" to `/etc/network/interfaces` (you can use other DNS addresses instead of google's i've used as example) as per https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration.  I don't know your linux so I can't be precise as to what you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to test your can access external, try

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

which confirms you are connected and can get external. If this works, but the pinging of google.com failed, it's a DNS issue.

A quick fix is to add

```
"nameserver 8.8.8.8"
```

to the end of `/etc/resolv.conf`. DNS is 'domain name service' & translates human names like google.com into their real ip address (numbers). This however is temporary and won't survive a reboot or networking services restart.

You make the change permanent via adding the nameserver to your NM (network manager) setup. On my Lubuntu 18.10 it's Preferences->Network->DNS and add a "8.8.8.8" there.

You could also add `dns-addresses 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` to `/etc/network/interfaces` (*you can use other DNS addresses instead of google's i've used as example*) as per https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration.

Comment: Did that do the trick, is it marked as solved now?